# Drag and Drop using images

Tags: java, android

I have this drag and drop on android studio, it works using image views. Once I pick an image view up using a OnLongListener and drop it to a blank image view which is the target, the target image view should change to the image view I have grabbed.

My Code

```
img6.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            DragShadow dragshadow = new DragShadow(v);
            ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
            v.startDrag(data, dragshadow, v, 0);
            return false;
        }
    });

    droptarget.setOnDragListener(new View.OnDragListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
            int dragEvent = event.getAction();
            int ImageViewID = v.getId();
            switch (dragEvent) {

                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                    break;

                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
                    break;

                case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                    droptarget.setImageResource(ImageViewID);
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

The setImageResource comes up as an error.

Answer (score 0):

`setImageResource` sets a drawable as the content of an ImageView. But you are trying to pass the id of a view to it

```
int ImageViewID = v.getId(); 
droptarget.setImageResource(ImageViewID);
```

Instead you can try something:

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView)v;
droptarget.setImageResource(imageView.getDrawable());
```

Comment: it doesn't work, where do you get image.getDrawable();

Comment: it was typing mistake. I have edited it imageView.getDrawable()

Answer (score 0):

You can send the Drawable code(int) (For example int value of R.id.some_image_view) in the ClipData of the View getting dragged. Then use that code to retrieve the correct Drawable to the Dropped-on-View.

```
droptarget.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(Integer.parseInt(code)));
```

Then force a redraw with:

```
droptarget.invalidate();
```

This do require you to override the OnLongClick listener though with your own custom one.